# How to add "select opened file" icon in Project tab in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, project

I know how to select an opened file via hotkey, but I can't understand, how to show this icon in the "Project" window?
["select opened file" icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQgvC.png)
Now I see this:
[project tab without icon "select opened file"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I94Z.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your images to the post, so that they are visible with the question. Thanks.

Comment: Seems "Always select opened file" option is enabled. Please check it under grey cog wheel.